# Comparing responses between groups and conditions

Tags: chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test, mcnemar-test

I have a group of subjects that were tested under 2 visual stimuli. Each stimuli was presented in 2 directions (the stimulus is a flow of objects, once left to right and then right to left). And the subjects were moving their heads from side to side (like saying "No").
We asked the subjects in each case (stimulus type + stimulus direction), if when the head moves towards the right and towards the left, they feel the stimulus goes: Slower, Same or Faster.

```
                      Left2Right    Right2Left

Head Left:Faster                    0   2
Head Left:Same                      0   7
Head Left:Slower                    9   0
    
Head Right:Faster                   2   1
Head Right:Same                     7   7
Head Right:Slower                   0   8
```

And a similar one for Stimulus 2.
I would like to compare the results with the same condition (stimulus direction and head direction) between the 2 stimuli and when head and stimulus go in the same direction in each stimulus, etc.

We first thought of Fischer Exact Test (3x2 or 2x2 grouping answers) but since we have the same subjects McNemar looked better. However we are still not sure.
Can anyone help with the test needed (an example of application in SPSS would be much much appreciated).

Thanks
Dario